# How to work with pydantic json field through dot

Tags: python, pydantic

I have such model, enum, field:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Json

class SlotActionEnum(Enum):
    NORMAL = 'normal'
    REASK = 'reask'


class ChannelMessage(Json):
    answerText: str
    slot_action: SlotActionEnum = SlotActionEnum.NORMAL 


class Request(BaseModel):
    conversationId: str
    channelMessage: ChannelMessage



o = Request(**{
    "conversationId": "id10",
    "channelMessage": "{\"answerText\": \"sadfg\", \"slot_action\": \"reask\"}"
})
```

Here is two problem:

1. `slot_action` cannot be accessed like that: `o.channelMessage.slot_action`

This causes AttributeError:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'slot_action'

If I access to this field via square bracket PyCharm highlights:

[image]

2. Value in `slot_action` is not SlotActionEnum but value like `reask` or `normal`
3. `slot_action` can be empty string. How could I replace empty string to `normal`?

What should I do to handle these problems? Should I do something like this:

```
class ChannelMessage(BaseModel):
    answerText: str
    slot_action: SlotActionEnum = SlotActionEnum.NORMAL

class Request(BaseModel):
    conversationId: str
    channelMessage: ChannelMessage

    def __init__(__pydantic_self__, **data: Any) -> None:
        channel_message = json.loads(data.pop('channelMessage'))
        if channel_message['slot_action'] == '':
            channel_message['slot_action'] = SlotActionEnum.NORMAL.value
        channel_message['slot_action'] = SlotActionEnum(channel_message['slot_action'])
        super().__init__(**data, channelMessage=channel_message)
```

? Well that works but looks ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from enum import Enum


class SlotActionEnum(Enum):
    NORMAL = 'normal'
    REASK = 'reask'


class ChannelMessage(BaseModel):
    answerText: str
    slot_action: SlotActionEnum = SlotActionEnum.NORMAL

    @validator("slot_action", pre=True)
    def valid_slot_action(cls, v):
        if v == "":
            return SlotActionEnum.NORMAL
        return v


class Request(BaseModel):
    conversationId: str
    channelMessage: ChannelMessage

    @validator("channelMessage", pre=True)
    def valid_channel_message(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return ChannelMessage.parse_raw(v)
        return v


o = Request(**{
    "conversationId": "id10",
    "channelMessage": "{\"answerText\": \"sadfg\", \"slot_action\": \"reask\"}"
})
```